# clojure - java interop (No matching ctor found)

Tags: java, class, clojure, interop

Consider the following lines of Java code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

(taken from the 'Getting Started' Example of the the  [HTML Unit Project](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html))

How would that be adopted to Clojure?

After adding the needed dependencies, I tried the following:

```
(import '[com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html HtmlPage])
(import '[com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit WebClient])

(let [wc (WebClient.)
      hp (HtmlPage. (.getPage wc "http://www.something.."))]
   ;;...)
```

but I get this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found f\
or class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage, compiling:(*cider-repl l\
ocalhost*:30:16)
```

Anybody knows why?

---

**EDIT:**

As noted in a comment, calling the constructor of HtmlPage might not be necessary. However the following code yields an error as well, though another one:

```
    (.getPage (WebClient.) "http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net")

IllegalArgumentException Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.im\
pl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver  org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.isT\
rue (Validate.java:155)
```

Comment: That second error seems unrelated to the first one. I'm just grasping at straws here, though; without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes your dependency configuration, it's hard to say what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```clj
(HtmlPage. (.getPage wc "http://www.something.."))
```

is equivalent to this:

```clj
(new HtmlPage (. wc getPage "http://www.something.."))
```

which is equivalent to this Java code:

```java
new HtmlPage(wc.getPage("http://www.something.."))
```

Just leave out the extra constructor call:

```clj
(.getPage wc "http://www.something..")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately your propose is not working - I added something to the original post relating to this.

Comment: There is also a - quite antique - clojure wrapper for this library: https://github.com/hippiehunter/clj-htmlunit, I could not figure out their interop approach yet.

Comment: @AntonHarald [Their call to `getPage`](https://github.com/hippiehunter/clj-htmlunit/blob/master/src/clj_htmlunit/web_client.clj#L45) looks exactly the same as the one I gave in my answer.

Comment: it looks like that I could solve it now, thanks for the help! it was some version confusions causing it.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to Sam's answer that the real issue is that the way your Clojure code is written doesn't define your constructors in a way that would match your Java code.

```
(ClassA.)
```

is equivalent to

```
new ClassA();
```

Any parameters are in the same order

```
(ClassA. param1 param2)
```

is equivalent to

```
new ClassA(param1, param2);
```

The dot (.) after the class name creates a new object and a dot before a name calls a method. You need the object calling the method too. Say for example that classA is an object of ClassA and has methods callMethodNoParams() and callMethod(ClassB param1, ClassC param2).

```
(.callMethodNoParams classA)
```

is equivalent in Java to

```
classA.callMethodNoParams();
```

Another example:

```
(.callMethod classA param1 param2)
```

is equivalent in Java to

```
 classA.callMethod(param1, param2);
```

Another example that creates an object while calling a method:

```
classA.callMethod(param1, new ClassC(someParam));
```

is equivalent in Java to

```
(.callMethod classA param1 (ClassC. someParam))
```